# Simple Registration on Symfony 2 wrong action

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I used the Symfony 2 documentation to create a simple registration.
But now i have two little problems. The password fields, which I created with the Form Builder, be time in plain text.

The second problem is that the action of the form is not used the correct route. When I press the submit button, I get the standard page.

Has anyone of you an idea, which may be related?

If you still parts of the code needed, I like to add these.

Greetings

Comment: [reading the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) ;)

Answer (score 0):

did you set it to a password type? eg

```
$builder->add('password', 'password)
```

Or can do repeated field

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
));
```

When you build the form do you set action?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Type(), $type, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('your_route'),
));
```